# Выяснить, сколько в массиве совпадающих значений

Tags: pascal, алгоритм

Как узнать, сколько в массиве совпадающих по величине чисел?

Допустим, есть двумерный массив 4 на 4 (рандомный). Это понятно, но что же делать дальше? Нужно выделить ещё один массив, или что?

Comment: Написал исходник.

Answer (score 4):

Сортируете любым методом, а затем:

1. Если надо просто узнать количество совпадающих чисел, считаете сколько раз предыдущее значение совпадает с текущим значением.
2. Если нужно узнать количество совпадений каждого из чисел, тогда по массиву шагаете, считаете каждое совпадение, как только предыдущее отлично от текущего, выводите результат для предыдущего. Плюс добавьте условие вывода > 1 элемента.

Этот вариант больше подходит, когда память жалко, а на время обработки можно забить.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так: сохранил бы каждое число, имеющееся в матрице, в один одномерный массив. А в другой массив записывал бы сколько таких чисел в матрице. Хотя здесь, как мне кажется, лучше создать объект типа запись с 2-мя полями: "элемент" и "встретился раз", потом создать массив этих записей. В цикле в поле "элемент" записать число, если его в этом массиве ещё нет, и во вложенном цикле считать количество таких же чисел. Примерно так...

Идея [@Dex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/878/dex), конечно, в плане реализации проще, вот код.

```
    Const
      N0=40;

    Var
      A: Array[0..N0-1, 0..N0-1] Of Integer;
      Mas: Array[0..N0*N0-1] Of Integer;
      Col, MasInd, ElCol, SortInd: Word;
      Tmp: Integer;
      i, j, N: Byte;

    begin
      Repeat
        Write('N = ');
        ReadLn(N);
      Until ((N>0) And (N<40)); // < 40 так задумано, 
// 39-ый (40-ой) элемент нужен для последнего цикла, если N=39

      MasInd:=0;
      Randomize;
      For i:=0 To N-1 Do
        Begin
          For j:=0 To N-1 Do
            Begin // здесь делаю сразу всё то, что связано с матрицей
              A[i, j]:=Random(10);
              Mas[MasInd]:=A[i, j]; // заполняю массив элеметами
              Inc(MasInd);
              Write(' ', A[i, j]:3);
            End;
          WriteLn;
        End;

      ElCol:=N*N; // число элементов массива
      Dec(ElCol);

      WriteLn;

// пузырьковая сортировка: один из самых медленных алгоритмов, но краткий по объёму кода
      For MasInd:=0 To ElCol-1 Do
        For SortInd:=MasInd+1 To ElCol Do
          If (Mas[MasInd]>Mas[SortInd]) Then
            Begin
              Tmp:=Mas[MasInd];
              Mas[MasInd]:=Mas[SortInd];
              Mas[SortInd]:=Tmp;
            End;

     { For MasInd:=0 To ElCol Do
        WriteLn(Mas[MasInd]); проверка сортировки }

      MasInd:=0;
      While (MasInd<=ElCol) Do // здесь и осуществляется перебор
        Begin
          i:=0;
          Tmp:=Mas[MasInd];
          Repeat // здесь считаю количество (можно переписать и с While)
            Inc(i); // количество
            Inc(MasInd);
          Until (Tmp<>Mas[MasInd]);
          WriteLn('Element ', Mas[MasInd-1], ' vstretilsya ', i ,' raz.');
        End;

      ReadLn;
    end.
```

Comment: А исходник можно хотя бы примерный может потом сам допилю. а то я не понимаю как это осушествить

Comment: Решал однажды подобную задачу, когда к олимпиаде готовился... Исходник найти не могу. Мог бы написать, но сегодня не могу. Смогу только завтра или послезавтра.

Comment: А не проще было бы тогда объявить список в котором бы хранилось два числа и указатель?

Comment: Не понял что за список. Запись, что-ли?

Answer (score -1):

простенький алгоритм:

```
var
  Array1: array [0..9] of array [0..9] of integer;
  i, z: integer;
 begin

 // заносите в первую строку массива числа для сравнения
 // заносите во вторую строку массива нули

  // для каждого числа первой строки
  for I := 0 to 9 do
   // пробегаете всю строку
   for z := 0 to 9 do
    // и сравниваете числа
    if Array1[i, 0] = Array1[z, 0] then
     // Если равны, то второй строке текущего числа прибавляете 1
     Array1[i, 1]:= Array1[i, 1] + 1;
 end;
```

дальше, если надо, можно сделать цикл, который будет отсеивать повторяющиеся числа, чтобы можно было выдать нормальный результат без повторов

Comment: Для этого
for I := 0 to 8 do
   for z := I to 9 do